filtragem refinada em Djqngo
Como em Django, eu posso criar uma filtragem refinada, numa lista de itens exibidos ao usuário, seria algo como ( filtro 1 aplicado, retorna resultado, ai aplica filtro2, e retorna o resultado dentro dos elementos retornados no filtro 1, por exemplo de uma lista de cadastros, entre homens e mulheres, casados e solteiros com e sem filhos,, selecionar somente os homens e casados e sem filhos,) acho que deu para entender segue abaixo a minha view para listar e o template que renderiza essa pagina
Eu creio que o problema esta no fato, de que  cada vez que aplico um filtro, toda a pagina e recarregada, e so isso que consigo ver como unica opção.
Poderiam me explicar, minha aplicação, estou usando tudoem CBV.

Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português (versão curta). Antes de usar o site faça o [tour], leia [ask], saiba o que é um [mcve] e para mais informações sobre o funcionamento da plataforma [help].

Por favor, não duplique perguntas. Se precisar comentar ou melhorar a pergunta faça na pergunta original.
